# Field Updateable on Create but Read Only on edit

Tags: sharing, apex-sharing, custom-profile

I have a custom field on account object (Id number). I want a custom profile's users to be able to:

1. On new account insert id number
2. On edit i want this field to be read only, so as users of these profiles won't be able to edit existing accounts' Id numbers.

How could we achieve this, and which is the best way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple validation rule would solve your issue. You can use **[isnew()](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm)** and **[ischanged(fieldname)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm)** function the formula builder of validation rule and fire the validation based on that.

> **IsNew()** Checks if the formula is running during the creation of a new
> record and returns TRUE if it is. If an existing record is being
> updated, this function returns FALSE.

> **IsChanged(fieldname)** Compares the value of a field to the previous value and
> returns TRUE if the values are different. If the values are the same,
> this function returns FALSE.

Comment: It could be Sanket, thank you so much for this clever solution.